# Custom Materials on all sides of a Polygon using DataSource

Tags: cesiumjs

Is it possible to add custom materials to each side of a polygon if it is created by calling viewer.dataSources.add(data) ?

I was originally using the extrudedHeight property to set different heights of my objects, but I learned that this limits the ability to set a material on any side except for the top of the polygon.

If I select the entity afterwards using the entities.getById function, I am able to reset the extrudedHeight property to 0, and THEN set the height property of the polygon which allows it to keep the same height without relying on the extrudedHeight property. As far as I can tell, however, the entity still behaves the same way when I try to set the material again.

Is there no difference between the height and extrudedHeight properties? In any case, is there a way that I can have my custom material on the outter edges of the polygon, rather than the top, without having to build a custom polygon for each of my objects (which, in this case, are buildings)?

My code:

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer', {
      imageryProvider : new Cesium.createOpenStreetMapImageryProvider({
          url : 'http://tile.stamen.com/watercolor/'
      }),
      baseLayerPicker : false
    });

    var dataSource = Cesium.GeoJsonDataSource.load('../data/mDataSource.json').then(function(data)  {

      viewer.dataSources.add(data);
      viewer.zoomTo(data);

      var entities = data.entities.values;
      var colorHash = {};

      for (var i = 0; i < entities.length; i++) {

      var entity = entities[i];
      var name = entity.name;
      var color = colorHash[name];

      if (!color) {
          color = Cesium.Color.fromRandom({
              alpha : 1.0
          });

          colorHash[name] = color;
      }

      entity.polygon.material = '../data/img/myMaterial.png';
      entity.polygon.extrudedHeight = 10;
  }

    var mEntity = viewer.dataSources.get(0).entities.getById("mId");
    mEntity.polygon.extrudedHeight = 0;
    mEntity.polygon.height = 10;
    mEntity.polygon.material = '../data/img/myMaterial.png';
  });
```

EDIT: I've also heard that in order to achieve what I'm looking for, I would need to design my own custom polygon. If this is the case, is it possible to use custom polygons with data sets brought in through the Cesium.GeoJsonDataSource method?